# How to display output results of a program in hyperlinked format in Python3/ PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Am performing some text search operation in files. The output will display the lines if it contains the text inputted for search. I have completed the code till this. Now I want to display this output lines in some widget, these lines should be hyperlinked, when we click on the output line it will open the file which has this text.
The line can also contain plain text or some HTML code which I want to display AS-IS, for example:
If we search for "table.jsp" and the line's content is as follow which is available in A.txt:

```
<a href=\"JavaScript:tableClick('../table.jsp?id="+ RevId +"', '')>Link</a>
```

then the output in widget should be AS-IS:

```
<a href=\"JavaScript:tableClick('../table.jsp?id="+ RevId +"', '')>Link</a>
```

**NOT**:

[Link](https://www.google.com)

Now when click on `<a href=\"JavaScript:tableClick('../table.jsp?id="+ RevId +"', '')>Link</a>` it should open A.txt file.

How can we achieve this in PyQt5 or using any other GUI in Python3?
I tried displaying the outputs in QLabel (PyQt5) but the output for HTML is coming as :

[Link](https://www.google.com)

Comment: Are you saying you want to display the HTML code as plain text? You can call `setTextFormat(Qt.PlainText)` on the QLabel.

Comment: No, not exactly, As I said in the question the output will be "<a href=\"JavaScript:tableClick('../table.jsp?id="+ RevId +"', '')>Link</a>". But when we click on this text it should open the file which has this text. So, if Question.txt file has above text (i.e. <a href..) then when we click on "<a href.." it should open File.txt. Kind of similar to what Notepad++ "Find in Files" result does.

Comment: Edited the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: I see. When you say "open the file", do you mean open it in another app or display the contents in the GUI like using a QTextEdit?

Comment: For now am going to open it in a user preferred editor (may be Notepad++ for jsp's), but later it can be QTextEdit. So am OK with any input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to achieve this. You can replace the visible text part of the HTML code with the entire link, replacing the special characters `< > "` with their HTML escape strings `&lt; &gt; &quot;`. For example, the text 
`<a href="file:file1.txt">Link</a>` becomes:

```
<a href="file:file1.txt">&lt;a href=&quot;file:file1.txt&quot;&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;</a>
```

When you call `setOpenExternalLinks(True)` on a QLabel, it will open links with the default application using `QDesktopServices.openUrl()`. In the case below, I have a file called `file1.txt`, and when I click on the QLabel it opens the file in the application that would be chosen if I double clicked on the file.

```
import sys, re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class LinkLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        visible = text.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;')
        i, j = re.search('>(.*)<', text).span()
        self.setText(text[:i+1] + visible + text[j-1:])
        self.setOpenExternalLinks(True)


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(LinkLabel('<a href="file:file1.txt">Link</a>'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: If we do not want to replace each html character manually using replace method, alternatively we can also use html.escape method.